# PHP json object

Tags: php, json

This is my json file:

```
$json='{
    "mainmenu": [
    {
        "title": "Main Menu 1",
        "url": "some url"
    },
    {
        "title": "Main Menu 2",
        "url": "some url2"
    }
    ],
    "submenu": {
    "my submenu 1": [
    {
        "title": "Sub menu title",
        "url": "some url"
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub menu title",
        "url": "some url"
    }
    ],
    "another submenu":[
    {
        "title": "Sub menu title",
        "url": "some url"
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub menu title",
        "url": "some url"
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub menu title",
        "url": "some url"
    }
    ]
}
}';
```

I am able to find out number of main menu with this:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json);
echo sizeof($data->mainmenu);
```

But how can I get the total number of submenu? How can I get the name of each submenu?

Thank you.

Comment: After you decode your JSON, you have simple multidimensional array. Just print_r/var_dump it to see how it looks like. Then build a loop to check whatever you want.

Comment: @user1995781 have you tried my anwer

Comment: @SatishSharma Tried with your answer. Your answer works the best!! Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
$arr2 = $arr->submenu;

$total_submenu = 0;
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$val)
{
    $total_submenu += sizeof($val);
}

echo $total_submenu; // ouput 5 according to your json
```

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the count of submenu objects:

```
echo count((array)$data->submenu));
```

Loop through the indexes of the `submenu` array:

```
foreach(array_keys((array)$data->submenu) as $obj) {
    // $obj will be the name of each submenu
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now, how can I get the submenu info? If refer it directly it will be `$data->submenu->submenu1[0]->title;`. How to do it dynamically? I tried with `$data->submenu["submenu1"][0]["title"]` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` to iterate that `$data` array (use `var_dump()` to see full structure).

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer

```
$count = count(json_decode($json, true));
```